# R programming: getting error in apply() function and kmeans() function

Tags: r, statistics, market-basket-analysis

I am doing a market basket analysis with R, and doing so I was calculating WSS for Elbow Method and then using `kmeans()` function as well.
I have used one normalized data frame pc1 and then we calculated the PCA and then in the code we have the following commands:-

```
pc1 <- princomp(na.omit(pc1))
plot(pc1)
loadings(pc1)
pc.df <- data.frame(pc1$x[,1:3])
names(pc.df)
wss <- (nrow(pc.df)-1)*sum(apply(pc.df,2,var))
for (i in 2:15) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(pc.df, nstart = 100 , iter.max = 1000,
                                 centers=i)$withinss)
```

Then while running this, I am getting the following error at 6th line of the code with `apply()` function:-

> Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :
>   object '2013-12-09' of mode 'function' was not found

and in the next line I am getting:-

```
Error in kmeans(pc.df, nstart = 100, iter.max = 1000, centers = i) :
more cluster centers than distinct data points.
```

The second error is clearly due to the number of clusters being greater than the distinct points, but does it has to do something with the previous error?

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Also if anyone knows a good site or  link for a pdf to learn about PCA and Elbow Test(in terms of market basket with examples) will be helpful as well.

Comment: `apply(pc.df,2,var)` The argument `var` doesnt seem correct. It is expected to be a function. What do you want to do with `apply`?

Comment: Please provide example data. Without knowing what `pc1` looks like, we can't really know what hinders `apply` to calculate the variance.

Comment: @MKR `var` is a function to compute the `variance` of a continuous measure

Comment: @Cath Correct. I had over-looked case of `v` in `var`.

Comment: it seems like we have a command such as "pc.df <- data.frame(pc1$x[,1:3])" and for this pc.df is coming as null. I want to know how pc1$x[,1:3] works.. PC1 has all integers and numerics along with one loading and matrix class columns.

Comment: matrix and loadings class columns coming due to the following **"pc1 <- princomp(na.omit(pc1))"** .. so we are calculating the PCA and then using the **" pc1$x[,1:3]"** command and then when we are running the apply() function it is giving the above error mentioned in the question

Comment: class of pc1 is **princomp** when we are doing **pc1$x[,1:3]**

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue.
There was a variable named "var" which was there in the variable list and at the sametime we are using var function in apply(). This is the reason for the following error:-

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :object '2013-12-09' of mode 'function' was not found
```

The variable **"var"** was assigned the value of **2013-12-09**